# Exporting txt files with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

def export(ip, channel_search_list):

```
if len(ip) > 0: 

        filename = "files//"+"output"+str(ip)+".txt"
        action = 'FullExport'
        menu_action = 'all'

        arg_list = '/home/venv/upnp/bin/python2.7 /home/code/upnp/Client/UPNP_Client_Cmd_Line.py'             
        arg_list += ' --action='
        arg_list += action
        arg_list += ' --ip='
        arg_list += (str(ip))
        arg_list += ' --menu='
        arg_list += menu_action

        x = subprocess.Popen(arg_list, shell=True)


        with open(filename, "w+") as output:
            subprocess.call(['python', arg_list], stdout=output, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

get_book_ids_func(filename, channel_search_list, ip)
```

I am trying to export some data to txt files with subprocess. But, with the above function, its directly outputting the data on the command screen. it does not export in the txt file. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: `subprocess.check_output` but, given it's Python, just import the other script as a module

Comment: Hi @Chris_Rands. Thanks for your answer. But, I did not get it. Do I need to replace the call method to check_output?

Comment: I can't make sense of the code you've posted. Please [edit] your question and at least correct its indentation. Exactly what data is it that you're trying to export? What does `get_book_ids_func()` have to do with the problem?